# Git clone makes filenames all lowercase

Tags: git, case-sensitive

We're cloning files onto Windows computers (Windows 10 Enterprise, 20H2) from an internally hosted Bitbucket repository using a recent version of git (2.33.0.windows.1).

Sometimes, when cloning the repository, or when pulling new files from the repository, the file will be all lowercase ie instead of `/some/folder/SomeFile.py` it is cloned as `some/folder/somefile.py` which breaks case sensitive imports in python. The file is named `some/folder/SomeFile.py` in the repository, and no file called `some/folder/somefile.py` ever existed in the repositiry.

This happens semi consistently for some users (ie they can retry the clone and it's ok but a later pull is all lowercase again), but never for other users and we can't find any difference between git settings that would cause this.

What can we do to fix this?

Comment: Is this really with a fresh clone in each case? I've heard of problems trying to change the case of an existing file, or collisions when two filenames only differ by casing, but I've never heard of a fresh close or checking out a newly added file causing such trouble.

Comment: Is there any chance you can create a dummy public repo on GitHub that reproduces the same problem? Also, can you share what version of Git and Windows you're using?

Comment: Using Windows 10 Enterprise at the 20H2 update (19042.1766) and git 2.33.0.windows.1.
Not sure I could create a repo to demonstrate the problem since I've no idea what causes the problem or how to reproduce it